# How do I update OpenSSL on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, security, update

It seems like Raspbian has not been updated yet to deal with the [Heartbleed bug](http://heartbleed.com). `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` doesn't update anything (this is a system which was freshly updated yesterday so it is all up to date otherwise).

When I do `sudo apt-get install openssl` it tells me the latest version is installed, while `openssl version` tells me 1.0.1e is still installed. The first non-vulnerable version of OpenSSL is 1.0.1g, so how do I update to this?

Comment: I just checked my OpenSSl version from raspbian and it uses 0.9.8 which is not vulnerable according to heartbleed.com

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The core affected package is `libssl1.0.0`, which if you can, just replace with the patched version, restart everything. You can try to download a binary, and manually install an arm-hf, using `dpkg` with the version `1.0.1e-2+deb7u5` for wheezy.

You can also use the `jessie` repository, just for this single one time update, which should get you version `1.0.1g-1`.

After install and reboot you it is strongly recommended to revoke all keys and certificates and regenerate everything from scratch, using new passwords and vectors.

---

As of **09/04/2014** the main wheezy repository uses the patched version `1.0.1e-2+deb7u5`  and as commented, you can get it like this:

```
> sudo apt-get update 
> sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Which will update the following packages:

`libssl1.0.0 openssh-client openssh-server openssl ssh`

---

*Here is how to selectively upgrade certain packages using jessie repository, without completely breaking wheezy, and will install the latest `g` version

Add the following two lines into `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

You then edit the file `/etc/apt/preferences` (create the file if doesn't exist) to tell apt in which repositories it should look to do an update. We put jessie on a low priorty so that when you use apt-get update it will ignore `jessie` and use `wheezy` repo instead. This is important for the step after this one.

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=wheezy
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: *
Pin: release n=jessie
Pin-Priority: 300

Package: *
Pin: release o=Raspbian
Pin-Priority: -10
```

Now, at your free will you can tell apt to use `jessie` instead.

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie install openssl libssl1.0.0 openssh-client openssh-server ssh
```

<sup>*[An extract from Chapter 6, Raspberry Pi Server Essentials.](http://raspberrypi-pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/raspberry-pi-server-essentials-my-book.html)</sup>

---

Comment: Can you show how to use the `jessie` repository for just one update?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn was your site really hacked or are you just out of ideas for now?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  The hosting company disabled my site a few months ago and my ISP blocks access to the site so I hadn't checked it in some time.  I used Google to view the cached content and indeed it looks suspect.  Thanks again.  Your book looks great, I previewed it on Amazon.

Comment: This has been fixed right now, and I updated the raspberry pi with the normal repositories.

Comment: Yep, this is in the current updates:

> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade

The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl1.0.0 openssh-client openssh-server openssl ssh

Comment: In my case, the latest version is `1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u6`. I'm not sure what the `rvt` portion is, but the `deb7u6` indicates to me that it's good. (Posting to help with searches.)