# Why are the Raspbian repositories so out of date?

Tags: raspbian, apt

I'm trying to install Owncloud, which is currently at version 6.0.3. However, Raspbian's version is from [about two years ago](http://owncloud.org/changelog/).

```
$ apt-cache show owncloud
Package: owncloud
Version: 4.0.4debian2-3.3
```

Similarly, Raspbian deluge (1.3.3) is [well over two years old](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/ReleaseNotes).

1. Is this common for many Raspbian packages?
2. Why does this repository lag behind so much?
3. Is there a way to get newer packages another repository, and/or would installing Pidora or Arch help?

Comment: Because all the new stuff is going into Jessie.. but Jessie is not 100% ready for ARM yet. I wrote somewhere on this site how to use Jessie to get certain latest packages.

Comment: Also, the main Debian repos are different to the Raspbian ones (i think...), so even though version 6.0.3 it [seems to be there](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/owncloud) for wheezy, i think it may take a while to filter over the raspbian ones (e.g. recompiling may be required for the Raspberry Pi's architecture/hardware)

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve your problem? Please answer your question or mark one correct. Thanks

Comment: @ppumkin I didn't get a reply from my comment 1.5 years ago. I can't remember clearly now, but I think that I had some kind of issue (as per the comment). I guess this question is now out-of-date, so probably best to just close it.

Comment: Greetings from the future, @SDsolar! Yes, I updated to stretch a couple of months ago. Took a day or so; I had problems with apache security mods and mysql. Apart from that it worked okay.

Answer (score 1):

I know link updates are frowned upon, but this is an internal link to what you need.

Half way down that answer it shows how you can select packages from Jessie repository so you can install the latest ones will be there.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/15061/894

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go after I've [fixed my pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/18307/is-it-possible-to-uninstall-packages-from-the-sd-card-using-another-computer).

Comment: I fixed my pi and followed your instructions to the tee, but `apt-get upgrade` is now trying to pull upgrades from the jessie repo, specifically `jessie/main linux-libc-dev armhf 3.13.10-1+rpi1+b2`.

Comment: How about a whole new OS?  Here it is, released Aug 2017:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71462/now-that-raspbian-stretch-has-been-released-should-jessie-users-rush-out-and-do

Comment: This addresses the complaint, "I don't like it that repositories are out od date" If you think that is the question intended, you should urge the OP. Personally I'm quite interested to know why they are,  but the answer is probably mundane. Nobody has come around to update them.

Comment: I think the newer versions are a lot more up to date now?? I know Jessie was very slow since not many people testing ARM based distros. But that should have changed drastically now as ARM is getting very, very popular and more PR's and updates should be coming in and available.  Also its a lot easier to build ARM packages now, before they had a small ARM Server that was overloaded and couldn't cope with all the builds getting queued.