# Now that Raspbian Stretch has been released, should Jessie users rush out and do the upgrade? Is it safe?

Tags: raspbian, noobs, raspbian-stretch

It has taken a while, but [RaspberryPi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) has now announced the official release of Stretch to replace Jessie.

Does this mean everybody should start changing their repos and doing the upgrade?

Myself, I am always opposed to adding or in this case, changing, repos for any reason.  The standard plain-vanilla Jessie repos have been time-tested.

> This reminds me of when Microsoft released Windows 2.0 after the ridiculous Windows 1.0 release.  A lot of people went right out and bought it.  (I know, because I was the one selling it to them in my home town).  The new number didn't make it any better.  In fact, there were even more bugs to work out.

**Upgrading to Stretch is not difficult, as per:**

[RASPBIAN STRETCH HAS ARRIVED FOR RASPBERRY PI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-stretch/)

Excerpt:

> To upgrade, first modify the files /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list. In both files, change every occurrence of the word ‘jessie’ to ‘stretch’. (Both files will require sudo to edit.)
>
> Then open a terminal window and execute

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

> Answer ‘yes’ to any prompts. There may also be a point at which the install pauses while a page of information is shown on the screen – hold the ‘space’ key to scroll through all of this and then hit ‘q’ to continue.

---

> Finally, if you are not using PulseAudio for anything other than Bluetooth audio, remove it from the image by entering

```
sudo apt-get -y purge pulseaudio*
```

---

The question is in the title.  Should we all rush out and do that to our stable systems, even before there is a Stretch NOOBS?  Have enough people done this to consider it safe?

Comment: May I be the first to comment: "It depends..."? ;)

Comment: Debian / Raspbian is the distro with the most conservative update regime. This is reflected in the version freeze of each release which is designated "stable".

Comment: Yes, they are.  I agree with both comments.  Myself, I am going to wait until I can do a fresh NOOBS install of it, then try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it is safe and generally unless you want a feature in stretch you don't need to upgrade. All Linux distros are usually really stable upon release due to testing although there is not much of a reason to upgrade unless you are having problems with your os at the moment.

Comment: I have assumed pretty much that was the case.   So when it is released as a NOOBS it will go on one of my underutilized Rpi3's.   My working units are tuned and stable.  Jessie has turned out to be very reliable for 24x7 operation.