# RetroPie does not load correctly on Raspbian

Tags: boot, raspbian-stretch, retropie

I have been trying to load Retro Pie on my Raspbian OS/Kodi but doesn't seem to work. The board is a Raspberry Pi 3B+. It's a 32 GB card and I plan on putting ROMs on a flash drive. When loading it goes into the windows but then kicks me out to the commands forum. What do I do?

Comment: all that happens without any errors or any messages?

Comment: What version of RetroPi are you using? It might be better to use their latest OS image which is Raspian +Retropi + Kodi. I believe that you can use a larger SD card on a 3B+, but it's selective as to which types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RetroPie fails to boot on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ with rainbow screen and flashing red led](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82350/retropie-fails-to-boot-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-with-rainbow-screen-and-flashi)

Comment: @Fabian, doesn't look like a duplicate of that question to me unless I'm misreading - the OP doesn't seem to be having the rainbow screen problem from what they've said.